# CMake cross platform use of generate_export_headers and inline template functions

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake, dllimport, dllexport

#### Background

Generate export headers generates dllimport/export, and equivalent explicit exports/imports for GCC.  However, unlike MSVC, GCC and Clang support visibility modifiers on *template* functions.  This apparently has [*actual real world consequences*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52203472/visibility-of-inline-template-functions).  And following [Craig Scott](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m0DwB4OvDXk), he heavily implies that one should be using export for inline as well, this is cooberated via https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/GenerateExportHeader.html where both recommend the use of the variables

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_VISIBILITY_PRESET hidden)
set(CMAKE_VISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN 1)
```

at the top of the CMakeLists.txt file. The problem is that MSVC appears to not support DLL export/import semantics on [template functions and classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60371557/c-template-class-dll-definition-of-dllimport-function-not-allowed).

#### Question

So how do I square the circle on these two incompatible requirements?  Best practices is recommending setting inlines to hidden, and while that only effects GCC and CLang, that means that exports are needed to make those symbols visible right? But because that isn't supported with MSVC, I can't use those exports on those symbols right in a cross platform way right?

Comment: You don't need to apply visibility macros on templates unless you want to export some explicit instantiations.

Comment: @Osyotr can you clarify what you mean?  My understanding is that `set(CMAKE_VISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN 1)` will make it so that regular template functions are hidden on GCC and Clang.  It is recommended to turn this on.  So if I want to use any template functions at all from GCC or clang, I must use the visibility macros on them period with this setting.

Comment: Please ignore my previous comment. Although you can omit export macro on template on both Windows and Unix, that can result in some consequences like two local statics would have different addresses. You can use export macro on template with MSVC, but you need to provide explicit instantiation for that template which is inconvenient.